# Does $\nabla_{(a}\eta_{b)} = \frac{1}{n}(\nabla_c\eta^c)g_{ab}$ hold for every smooth vector field $\eta^a$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Here's an exercise from Malament (2012, p. 87): For a metric $n$-manifold $(M, g_{ab})$ with a compatible connection $\nabla$, let $\eta^a$ be a conformal Killing field with respect to $g_{ab}$ (i.e. for some smooth scalar field $\Omega$, $\mathcal{L}_{\eta}(\Omega^2 g_{ab}) = {\bf 0}$). Then, show that $\nabla_{(a}\eta_{b)} = \frac{1}{n}(\nabla_c\eta^c)g_{ab}$.

But doesn't the last equation hold for *any* smooth vector field $\eta^a$? Consider the following:

\begin{align}
\nabla_{(a}\eta_{b)} & = \frac{1}{2}(\nabla_a(g_{bm}\eta^m)+\nabla_b(g_{am}\eta^m))\\
& = \frac{1}{2}(g_{bm}(\nabla_a\eta^m)+g_{am}(\nabla_b\eta^m))\\
\therefore g^{ba}\nabla_{(a}\eta_{b)}& = \frac{1}{2}(\delta^a_{\ m}(\nabla_a\eta^m)+\delta^b_{\ m}(\nabla_b\eta^m))\\
& = \nabla_m\eta^m\\
\therefore g_{ab}g^{ba}\nabla_{(a}\eta_{b)} & = (\nabla_m\eta^m)g_{ab}\\
\therefore \nabla_{(a}\eta_{b)} & = \frac{1}{n}(\nabla_m\eta^m)g_{ab}
\end{align}

This doesn't hinge on $\eta^a$ being a conformal Killing field. Is there some mistake in the derivation above, or is the restriction to conformal Killing fields not needed?

Comment: please do not use $n$ as a variable and as the dimension, especially in the same term of an equation

Comment: This is very confusing. If $\eta$ is a Killing field then $\nabla_{(\mu}\eta_{\nu)}=0$.

Comment: @K.defaoite it is *conformal Killing*, not Killing

Comment: Didier: $n$ in the fraction from the last equation is supposed to be the dimension of the manifold. But I changed some abstract indices from $n$ to $m$ for clarity.

Comment: My mistake, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accept your first $\therefore$, but not your second. You can't have three copies of the same index. You should have $g_{cd}g^{ba}\nabla_{(a}\eta_{b)}=g_{cd}\nabla_m\eta^m$. You now can't replace $g_{cd}g^{ba}$ with $n$, because it doesn't contract.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Thanks!

Comment: @fr_ Note that by doing so, you just show the tautology $\nabla_a\eta^a = \nabla_m \eta^m$